# `query |= transform` for modifying object values based on keys

Tags: jq

If you wanted to modify the value of some elements of an array, you could use something like

```
ARRAY |= map( if FILTER then TRANSFORM else . end )
```

or

```
ARRAY[] |= if FILTER then TRANSFORM else . end
```

However, I like the `QUERY |= TRANSFORM` pattern.

```
( ARRAY[] | select( FILTER ) ) |= TRANSFORM
```

All of these work for objects too (using `map_value` instead of `map`), as long as the filter only depends on the element values. But what if the filter depended on the key? I can come up with solutions such as

```
OBJECT |= with_entries( if .key | FILTER then .value |= TRANSFORM else . end )
```

But is there a way get something of the form `QUERY |= TRANSFORM` in that scenario?

---

**Concrete example**

```
.o |= with_entries( if .key | tonumber? // false then .value |= . + 100 else . end )
```

```json
{
  "o": {
    "a": 3,
    "b": 4,
    "1": 3,
    "2": 4
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "o": {
    "a": 3,
    "b": 4,
    "1": 103,
    "2": 104
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/dsB_umZ5zU) on jqplay

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a way:

```
( OBJECT | .[ keys_unsorted[] | select( FILTER ) ] ) |= TRANSFORM
```

As applied to the example:

```
( .o | .[ keys_unsorted[] | select( tonumber? ) ] ) |= . + 100
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/bNVONxP89E) on jqplay

Same idea, but using `to_entries` to give the query access to both the key and the value:

```
( .o | .[ to_entries[] | select( .key | tonumber? ) | .key ] ) |= . + 100
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/az3Nkvp7Td) on jqplay